# Spring Eclipselink doesn't properly delete connection table rows - table join column bind with null

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, many-to-many, eclipselink

My Spring boot server is working with eclipselink and postgres

I have entities of `User` and `Role`

```
@Entity
public class User {

   ...

   @Column(name = "USERNAME")
   private String userName;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
     name = "USER_ROLES",
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME"),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
   )
   private List<Roles> roles = new ArrayList<Roles>();

   ...
}
```

When I delete some of the roles on the user object and call user.update()

```
   updatedUser.setRoles(newRoles); // Remove 6 of the previous user roles
   userDao.update(updatedUser);
```

The roles are not deleted and here is what the EclipseLink does

```
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)--DELETE FROM "USER_ROLES" WHERE (("ROLE_ID" = ?) AND ("USERNAME" = ?))
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)-- bind => [7, null]
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)-- bind => [4, null]
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)-- bind => [5, null]
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)-- bind => [8, null]
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)-- bind => [19, null]
ClientSession(451252754)--Connection(1397904249)-- bind => [9, null]
```

Comment: What is in UpdatedUser? There is no indication why you have or would have null USERNAME - how do you have that column mapped in the User entity?

Comment: I've edited my question. BTW, when I fetch data using this mapping, it works well, and I get the roles as expected

Comment: USERNAME isn't part of the entity ID? JPA doesn't support this, and it will make caching and identity lookups to maintain and build this mapping potentially a problem for performance if not careful (but is fine in theory as it is). In this case, you will have to debug and check why it thinks the username property are now null. Have you changed this property value in this object within this context?

Comment: After changing the join column to userID, the operation works well, thanks!